# text to speech conversion throwing classcast exception

Tags: android, exception, text-to-speech

```
     private TextToSpeech tts;
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game);
        tts = new TextToSpeech(this,(OnInitListener) clickball); 
 }

 OnClickListener clickball=new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            score=scorenumber.nextInt(8);
            ballid=v.getId();

            if(score==4)
                {
            playgame(ballid,Integer.toString(score));
 dynamic_image.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.four_01));
                    dynamic_image.setVisibility(0x000000);
                    disablelayout();
                    timerfunc1(dynamic_image,R.drawable.four_02);


                    tts.setLanguage(Locale.US); 
                    tts.speak("Four", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null); 
                    dynamic_image.postDelayed(new Runnable(){             
                         @Override             
                         public void run() {   
                             dynamic_image.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.score4));
                             dynamic_image.setVisibility(0x000000);      
                             timerfunc(dynamic_image);
                         }         
                         }, 2200);
                    enablelayout4();

                }
   }
```

Given above is my source code.but it is throwing classcast exception when it runs..i want to convert the text "Four" to speech when the score is 4.plz anybody help me...i know given below line of code throwing the exception.but i dnt know hot to solve it..

```
          tts = new TextToSpeech(this,(OnInitListener) clickball);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answer...i gave clicklistener name in

```
    tts = new TextToSpeech(this,(OnInitListener) clickball);
```

actuallly i had to give the OnInitListener name there.i had changed the code like this..

fisrt implement TextToSpeech.OnInitListener 
and added its unimplemented method(OnInit).

```
 private TextToSpeech tts;
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game);
         tts = new TextToSpeech(this,this); 
OnClickListener clickball=new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            score=scorenumber.nextInt(8);
            ballid=v.getId();
            if (totalovers==0)
            {

                gameover();
                return;
            }
            if(score==4)
                {
                    playgame(ballid,Integer.toString(score));
                    dynamic_image.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.four_01));
                    dynamic_image.setVisibility(0x000000);
                    disablelayout();
                    timerfunc1(dynamic_image,R.drawable.four_02);

                    currentScore ="FOUR";
                    tts.setLanguage(Locale.US); 
                    tts.speak(currentScore, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

                    dynamic_image.postDelayed(new Runnable(){             
                         @Override             
                         public void run() {   
                             dynamic_image.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.score4));
                             dynamic_image.setVisibility(0x000000);      
                             timerfunc(dynamic_image);
                         }         
                         }, 2000);
                    enablelayout4();

                }
             }

   @Override      
    public void onInit(int status) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

this solved my problem...